# Home automation with php suggestions

Tags: javascript, php, html, home-automation

I'm working on a project with my brother for his home, specifically we are implementing home automation. The hardware part is ready and working; we handle everything with an UDOO.
Now that lights and the other devices are running with no problems, we want to build a front-end interface. There is a 7 inch android tablet in each room, but we would like to develop a multi-platform interface (so it could run on everything that can access internet). The idea is to create an HTML5 web application, using:

- php to handle the house data that will be stored in a database
- js(+AJAX) to create dynamic pages

I have pretty good knowledge in this environment, but I would like to know some suggestions on how to proceed.
My questions are:

1. Will I need a php framework (if so, which one)? [EDIT: ok, I'll use one of course :P]
2. Using WebSockets instead of polling will overload too much my application? If not, do they have compatibility with mobile browsers?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is too broad for this site. Please, look how to ask good questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will i need a php framework (if so, which one)?

You won't **need** it but of course it might help. (I would suggest [laravel](http://laravel.com))

> Is there anything better than polling the database throught php to
>   detect changes? (I searched about websockets, but I'm not sure if
>   those would work in mobile devices)

As you said already, web sockets can help you!

## Cross Platform Issue

There are many services out there like 
[cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) that you can use to build native applications from web technologies (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).